# iPhone - How can I get NSLog deep output custom class indented as it does for NSArrays or NSDictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I overload each subclass of my main class with a `description` method, but inside it, how may I do to make the attributes keeping indented as needed ? using \r does not help as the new item is not indented.

```
- (NSString*) description
{
    NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString string];

    [str appendFormat:@"One attribute : %d\r", self.oneAttribute];
    [str appendFormat:@"List : %@\r", self.myArrayOfCustomObjects];

    return str;
}

- (NSString*) description (on custom object)
{
    NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString string];

    [str appendFormat:@"One attribute : %d\r", self.oneAttribute];
    [str appendFormat:@"One other attribute : %d\r", self.oneOtherAttribute];

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, you must include the `#include <objc/runtime.h>` line in your source file to use this snippet.

---

You can use this code (I don't remember where I found it) to print out all of the properties of an object with nice formatting:

```
- (NSString*)description {
    NSMutableString* string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    unsigned int propertyCount;
    objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
        NSString *selector = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;

        SEL sel = sel_registerName([selector UTF8String]);

        const char* attr = property_getAttributes(properties[i]);
        switch (attr[1]) {
            case '@':
                [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s : %@\n", property_getName(properties[i]), [self performSelector:sel]]];
                break;
            case 'i':
                [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s : %i\n", property_getName(properties[i]), [self performSelector:sel]]];
                break;
            case 'f':
                [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s : %f\n", property_getName(properties[i]), [self performSelector:sel]]];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    free(properties);

    return string;
}
```

Comment: What about arrays of custom class objects ?

Comment: What about them? Are you saying that the array will not format each custom object or that you can't print the array at all?

Comment: It just writes on console? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that it does not act as a carriage return but just outputs as "\n" in the console

Comment: Just wanted to mention that if you wish to use this block of code, you will also need to add `#include <objc/runtime.h>` to your import statements.